# Where are the resources for Speech Rec SDK on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, speech-recognition

I just attended the Windows 8 Phone Speech Recognition session at the Build 2012 conference.  There are new/different capabilities for Phone 8 versus 7.  The presenter showed lots of specific code samples but after the session I'm now having trouble locating the namespaces, whether I need to download an SDK beyond Windows Phone 8 SDK, etc.

My question - Anyone have links to the documentation, samples, documentation specific to the APIs available in Phone 8?

By this time tomorrow the powerpoint presentation should be posted online and he had some links that I didn't write down quickly enough.  But in the meantime if someone has these links, I want to start now!

There's another question similar to this but it came was posted well before the conference and came to the wrong conclusions (links are to the old SDKs, etc).

Since today is Friday I bet it will be at least Monday before this slide deck is available.  I'll try emailing the presenter.

Update 1 - As far as binaries/assemblies go, it looks like just installing the Windows 8 SDK was sufficient.  I'm now able to use the Windows.Phone.Speech.Recognition namespace in a windows phone project.  I think this namespace is for the new stuff though I'm not positive.

Update 2 - Here's the closest thing I've found to documentation on the new SDK: [MSDN article published 10/23](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.speech.recognition%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).  Someone below also found this: [Another MSDN article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Speech-recognition-and-debe5858)  Here's yet another page: [MSDN 3rd related page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206958%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Update 3 - Found and successfully ran this sample app that's using the Windows 8 specific functionality: [MSDN speech rec and text to speech example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Speech-recognition-and-debe5858)

Final update - I now have everything I was looking for.  Hopefully this is helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

The API documentation is available on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207021(v=vs.105).aspx

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Good find.  It's a different page than I found and your page appears more general (that's a good thing).